# How can I prove the following inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If n is a positive integer, prove that $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}} < \dfrac{1\cdot3\cdot5\ldots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\ldots2n}$

Comment: A [stronger inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831072/using-sqrt1-t-leq-1-frac-t2-to-show-that-frac1-cdot3-cdot5-cdots2n-1) as $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \ge \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}$$ the result follows

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are you studying, that is, what tools might you be expected to use?

Comment: I was trying to use A.M > G.M and then put the prod operation and I thought I could get some way in middle, where I can reverse the sign of inequality. But that gave me, $\dfrac{1\cdot3\cdot5\ldots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\ldots2n}< \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Comment: Thanks @Albus Dumbledore, I understood how to prove that.